# Copy Table from one MySQL server to another

Tags: mysql, postgresql, export, dump

Is there a way to copy or export a large table from MySQL server to postgres without affecting servers performance.

I mean the table is very large and using mysqldump or any select query has bad consequences.

Overall my question is: if there is a way to get the copy of the production database or table without performance problems on production.

Comment: Is a consistent snapshot required? Is mysqldump causing "bad consequences" due to IO saturation? history length growth? or something else. If its IO saturation, using `mysqldump ... | pv` you could use the bandwidth limits of `pv` when piping mysqldump to file/postgresql server which limits the mysqldump rate.

Comment: Instead of copying from prod db directly, I'd suggest using one of standby servers for that purpose.

Comment: @danblack no consistent snapshot is not required. I'll probably try pv or write some script to extract chunks of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ignore changes that might happen while the copy is taking place...

Use the `PRIMARY KEY` to walk through the source table, fetch chunks of 100-1000 rows, copy them.  [*More on chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks), but adapt for just fetching, not deleting or updating.